# Rally request user story

Tags: api, rest, rally

We are using Rally Agile tool and Im trying to request all User Strories expecting to get list like:

S12
S13
S53
etc.

when I use [rally-server-address]/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement.js I receive list of:

US12
US43
etc.

Maybe I do not understand how to query User Stories clearly... Any help are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what is the problem with US12 US43 etc ? Is it the order? If you want the user stories to be ordered by FormattedID, you may specify it using `order` parameter, `&order=FormattedID`:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111&query=&start=1&pagesize=200&&fetch=FormattedID,ScheduleState&order=FormattedID
```

If you want your user stories prefix to be 'S' instead of 'US', Work Product Prefixes can be changed on a workspace level in Setup. Workspace administrator rights are necessary.
Also, when using v2.0 there is no need to have .js in the query.